# Promise rejection chaining from different js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have a controller.js from where I call an async method in the service.js . Despite having a '.catch' block to deal with the Promise rejection, the program never goes there. It ALWAYS enters the '.then' block before any Promise is resolved.

Here's the code for the "controller.js" (the caller)

```
const Service = require('./service')

Service.serviceQueryDB("abc")
.then(result => /*  Immediately comes here, not waiting for the Promise to be resolved */
    console.log("I should have waited, but I'm already here. Resolved : ", result)) 
.catch(e => /*  Never enters this block. The error thrown by Service.serviceQueryDB is never caught
                   because the program runs immediately to the '.then' block */
    console.error("Rejected : ", e))
```

Here's the code for the "service.js" (the provider)

```
async function queryDB(str){
    return new Promise((_,rej) =>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("Program is on DB now")
            rej("Query done!") /*I am 'rej'ecting the Promise*/
        },1000)
    })
}


async function serviceQueryDB(str){

        setTimeout(()=>{
            
            queryDB(str)
            .then( _ => {
                return new Promise((res)=>{
                    res("Query sucessfull")
                })
            })
            .catch(e => { /* the Promise rejection from the queryDB() is caught HERE, which is fine */
                return new Promise((_,rej) => {
                    console.error(e) /*  prints this 'Query done!', which is fine */
                    rej("Query unsuccessful") /*  however, this 'rej'ection is NOT caught in the controller, 
                                                      from where the method is called. Why? */
                })
            })
            
        }, 1000)
}

module.exports = {queryDB, serviceQueryDB}
```

So, the exception thrown should be caught on the controller.js and "Query unsuccessful" should be printed in the variable `result` here: `console.log("I should have waited, but I'm already here. Resolved : ", result))`

PS - if you copy/paste the code into two separate files and run `node .\controller.js`, you'll be able to reproduce the error

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing is returned from `serviceQueryDB(str)`.  The caller is applying then to null.  To get what you want, you'll need to manufacture and return a promise in that function, having it resolve when the timeout expires.  Better yet, return the promise returned by `queryDB`,  (and *don't* wrap that in a new promise)

Comment: `serviceQueryDB` could be re-written as: `function serviceQueryDB(str) { return queryDb(str); }`

Comment: yeah, I understand your guys logic. Thanks for taking the time to write it out. I'm learning js, and having trouble with a more complicated piece of code, but I wanted to transpose a similar logic to stackoverflow, so others could reproduce the error. That's why I had these wrappers

Answer (score 0):

ok, so, I was fumbling around with the code, got a break and some coffee, and the answer is: I have to signal unequivocally that a Promise is being return by `serviceQueryDB()`

So if I change the code in that method on "service.js" to this:

```
async function serviceQueryDB(str) {
  return new Promise((res,rej) => { /* have to signal that the return will return a Promise - and that this return is the ONLY possibility of a return value*/
        
    setTimeout(() => {
      queryDB(str)
        .then(_ => {
          res("Query sucessfull")
        })
        .catch(e => { 
          rej("Query unsuccessful") 
        })            
    }, 1000)
  })
}
```

It works fine.

Prints:

```
Program is on DB now 
Rejected :  Query unsuccessful
```

Everything else stays the same

Comment: Yes, a lot of people use variants of this: `const wait = time => new Promise(resolve  => setTimeout(resolve, time))` as a kind of toolbox function for delay in promise code.  Whenever you want to wait first, just say `return wait(1000).then(() => /*whatever*/)`

Answer (score 0):

A more maintainable form of the OP's approach...

```
const wait = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));

async function serviceQueryDB(str){
  return wait(1000)
  .then(() => {
    return queryDB(str)
  })
  .then(() => {
    return res("Query successful");
  });
}
```

When you later decide to remove the artificial waits, there's less editing...

```
async function serviceQueryDB(str){
  return queryDB(str)
  .then(() => {
    return res("Query successful");
  });
}
```